# Restart theorem counter to 1 by book chapter

Tags: numbering, environments

I am using `\documentclass{book}` with the `amsmath` and `amsthm` packages. Each chapter is a standalone paper, so I want the theorems in each chapter to begin with 1. How do I do this?

Here's a MWE.

```
\documentclass[printer]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Blahblah}
\begin{theorem}{This is Theorem 1 as it should be}
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}{This is Theorem 2 as should be}
\end{theorem}

\chapter{Blibli}

\begin{theorem}{I need this to be Theorem 1!}
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]`

Comment: Take a look at the `chngcntr` package which deals in general with this sort of thing.

Comment: @Tom This adds the chapter number before the theorem number, to produce Theorem 1.1 and Theorem 1.2, and then Theorem 2.1. I want to suppress the chapter number.

Comment: @Peter Wilson I took a look but I'm too much of a newbie to know what to do with it!

Comment: OK, I think I found a simple solution. Writing \setcounter{theorem}{0} at the beginning of the new chapter seems to reset the theorem numbers!

Answer (score 1):

If don't want manually write `\setcounter{theorem}{0}` every time, you could do this:

```
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\arabic{theorem}}

\begin{document} 
\chapter{Blahblah} 
\begin{theorem}
This is Theorem 1 as it should be
\end{theorem}
\begin{theorem}
This is Theorem 2 as should be
\end{theorem}

\chapter{Blibli}
\begin{theorem}
I need this to be Theorem 1! 
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This does what you want using the `chngcntr` package. Please read the package manual again.

```
% thmcntrprob.tex  SE 646889

\documentclass[printer]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin*{theorem}{chapter}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Blahblah}
\begin{theorem}{This is Theorem 1 as it should be} \end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}{This is Theorem 2 as should be} \end{theorem}

\chapter{Blibli}

\begin{theorem}{I need this to be Theorem 1!} \end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `chngcntr` is no longer needed.

Comment: @egreg Why is `chngcntr` no longer needed? Perhaps it is now part of basic LaTeX; if so how does anyone know about it?

Comment: It's described in one of the `ltnews`